# when we should create new layout in android

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, layout

I have two activities that work in so similar together, is it better to create separate activities and layout or I use just one activity and layout but control differences using if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much are the two activities different.

For example if you have `AddSomethingActivity` and `EditSomethingActivity` which are pretty much the same, except that `EditSomethingActivity` will pre-load some data into fields than yes, you should use the same `Activity` and layout for this two activities.

But if you would use much of if statements, it would not add to code readability and you should use two different Activities.

One more thing to know. If your layouts are the same, you can use the same layout in more than one `Activity` class.